# I want to create a link in database column value which value i viewed in my blade page in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to create a link in database column value which value I viewed in my blade page in laravel. In my databese I have a table. I already viewed a value. Now I want to create a link on this value by table id. It means suppose I have a column name `class_name` and its value image processing. It has an id in my database. So I have many class name and id in database. I want to create a link by class id. That's why user can click on class name like Image processing class and he can enter the only image processing class. As like if user click another class name he must should to enter another class.

I already make my route:

```
Route::get('/link-class/{id}', [
'uses' => 'classroomdata@link',
'as' => 'link.class',
'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

But I don't know how I write this in controller.

```
public function link(Request $request, $id)
{

}
```

And I also don't know what should be the link to put here

```
<div class="floating-box"><h4><a href=" ">{{ $newclass->class_name}}</a></h4><h5> Section: {{ $newclass->section}}</h5><img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">Teacher: {{ Auth::user()->name}}</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes i got it.
Route should be:

```
Route::get('/link-class/{class_id}', [
'uses' => 'classroomdata@link',
'as' => 'class',
'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

And controller:

```
 public function link($id)
{
    //echo "class id: ".$id;
    return view('class');
}
```